# Spring Boot Multi Cache Framework using Cache Resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am trying to use multiple cache frameworks in Spring boot application using the java configuration

But , I am not able to convert the org.ehcache.Cachemananger object to springframework.cache.CacheManager Object to get it registered in cache Resolver.

Below code is showing error at build time:

```
 @Bean(name="ehCacheManager")
public CacheManager ehcacheManager() {
    return new JCacheCacheManager(jCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}


@Bean(name="ehCacheResolver")
public CacheResolver ehcacheResolver() {
    return new CustomCacheResolver(ehcacheManager());
}
```

Showing error:

```
[ERROR] cache/mongo/configure/CacheConfiguration.java:[55,16] canno
t access javax.cache.CacheManager
  class file for javax.cache.CacheManager not found
```

Is there any way i can convert javax CacheManager to Spring CacheManager ?

Comment: Can you please share the method definition of jCacheCacheManager().

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Below is the definition for the jCacheCacheManager    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "application.cache.ehcache", havingValue = "enable")
    public JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheCacheManager() {
        JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCMFB = new JCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        File file = new File("classpath:spring/ehcache.xml");
        URI uri = file.toURI();
        jCMFB.setCacheManagerUri(uri);
        return jCMFB;
    }